# Validate complete CSV file in NodeJS (header line, data types etc)

Tags: node.js, validation, csv, types

How can I validate complete CSV file in NodeJS:

- check if every line has corresponding delimiter and newline character (LF)
  (if header line has ";" delimiter, the rest lines should too)
- check if every line has correct/expected number of columns
- check if header line has correct/expected column names
- check if rest of lines have values of correct data type ?

Columns number and columns names would be predefined.

Comment: I know about csv parser but how to assure all steps above? If I pass desired delimiter to parser, and if everything is ok except on line X, will it return error like "file invalid, wrong delimiter on line x" ? Also, how can I test every line of CSV against desired newline character? etc.

Comment: Some CSV examples with the desired output would probably help to create a specific answer